# PowerShell: Get Processor Utilization of a Process Using Proc ID

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get processor utilization of a process using the ID. I have the need to watch when a process is using 0% CPU. The problem is that I can have multiple processes with the same name so using the

```
get-counter -Counter "\Processor(<process Name>)\% Processor Time"
```

because it could potentially catch a different process by the same name. I also can't put it in a job because the process I am trying to capture is a sub process of a command line that instantly goes to 0%.

I hope that I am able to get the processor percentage for just one process based off of ID or some other distinct characteristic.

I did searching online all over this site and general web and can find articles on finding it by name just not process ID.

Comment: You can get the ID from the related counter: `get-counter -Counter "\Processor(<process Name>)\ID Process"`

Comment: So I have the ID already but I need to be able to tie the ID to the Processor time. The return only gives me the ID but doesn't give ID and CPU utilization so there is no way to correlate the two. Unless I am missing a piece.

Comment: how about `$cpu = (Get-Process -Id 42820).Cpu` ?

Comment: ".CPU" is actually CPU usage time. It will continually clock upward until the process is closed. I found my answer though. It takes a little math and some WMIObjects to get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up figuring out how to do this. Using WMI Object "Win32_perfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process" I was able to get the Processor time, the threads and then using "Win32_ComputerSystem" I could then take that and make a calculation of (*)/

```
(((get-wmiobject -class Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process | where {$_.IDProcess -eq "<ID Number>"} | select idprocess, name, percentprocessortime, ThreadCount).percentprocessortime) * (Get-CimInstance Win32_ComputerSystem).NumberOfLogicalProcessors)/(get-wmiobject -class Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process | where { $_.idprocess -eq "<ID Number>" } | select idprocess, name, percentprocessortime, threadcount).Threadcount)
```